# Python sockets data sent and received are not the same

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, raspberry-pi

I have a raspberry pi and usb webcam. I will take an image from the USB webcam I connected to the Raspberry Pi and send this image to my computer. My computer will perform a few operations on this image and send the resulting data back to the Raspberry. The program will repeat these steps as long as it runs (infinite loop). Raspberry pi sends data, but the length of the data the computer receives and the data sent by the raspberry pi are not the same. How can I solve this problem

Server.py :

```
import socket
import cv2
import io
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import struct

def encode_image(frame):
    stream = io.BytesIO()
    frame = cv2.resize(frame, (640, 480))
    frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    frame = Image.fromarray(frame)
    frame.save(stream, format="JPEG")
    stream.seek(0)
    return stream

def decode_image(image_bytes):
    stream = io.BytesIO(image_bytes)
    return cv2.cvtColor(np.array(Image.open(stream)), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

server_socket = socket.socket()
server_socket.bind(('0.0.0.0', 8000))
server_socket.listen(0)
c, addr = server_socket.accept()

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    x = encode_image(frame).read()
    print(len(x))
    print(x)   
    c.send(struct.pack('<L', len(x)))
    c.send(x)
    data = c.recv(1024)
    if data == "q":
        break
    print(data.decode('utf-8'))

c.close()
server_socket.close()
```

Client.py :

```
import socket
import cv2
import io
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import struct

cl_socket = socket.socket()
cl_socket.connect(('192.168.1.108', 8000))


def encode_image(frame):
    stream = io.BytesIO()
    frame = cv2.resize(frame, (640, 480))
    frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    frame = Image.fromarray(frame)
    frame.save(stream, format="JPEG")
    return stream.getvalue()

def decode_image(image_bytes):
    stream = io.BytesIO(image_bytes)
    return cv2.cvtColor(np.array(Image.open(stream)), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

while True:
    image_len = struct.unpack('<L', cl_socket.recv(struct.calcsize('<L')))[0]
    print(image_len)
    if not image_len:
        break
    image_bytes = io.BytesIO()
    image_bytes.write(cl_socket.recv(image_len))
    image_bytes.seek(0)
    print(image_bytes.getvalue())
    image_bytes.seek(0)
    x = decode_image(image_bytes.read())
    cv2.imshow('frame', x)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
    
cl_socket.close()
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You should consider using a loop to receive all the data since it may not be received in a single call to 'recv'.

Also, when sending data from the client to the server, you need to encode the string before sending and decode it after receiving.

**Server.py:**

```
import socket
import cv2
import io
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import struct

def encode_image(frame):
stream = io.BytesIO()
frame = cv2.resize(frame, (640, 480))
frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
frame = Image.fromarray(frame)
frame.save(stream, format="JPEG")
stream.seek(0)
return stream.read()

def decode_image(image_bytes):
stream = io.BytesIO(image_bytes)
return cv2.cvtColor(np.array(Image.open(stream)), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

server_socket = socket.socket()
server_socket.bind(('0.0.0.0', 8000))
server_socket.listen(0)
c, addr = server_socket.accept()

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
ret, frame = cap.read()
x = encode_image(frame)
image_len = struct.pack('<L', len(x))
c.sendall(image_len)
c.sendall(x)

data = c.recv(1024)
if data.decode('utf-8') == "q":
    break

c.close()
server_socket.close()
```

**Client.py:**

```
import socket
import cv2
import io
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import struct

cl_socket = socket.socket()
cl_socket.connect(('192.168.1.108', 8000))

def encode_image(frame):
stream = io.BytesIO()
frame = cv2.resize(frame, (640, 480))
frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
frame = Image.fromarray(frame)
frame.save(stream, format="JPEG")
return stream.getvalue()

def decode_image(image_bytes):
stream = io.BytesIO(image_bytes)
return cv2.cvtColor(np.array(Image.open(stream)), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

while True:
image_len = struct.unpack('<L', cl_socket.recv(struct.calcsize('<L')))[0]
if not image_len:
    break

image_data = b''
while len(image_data) < image_len:
    to_read = min(image_len - len(image_data), 4096)
    image_data += cl_socket.recv(to_read)

x = decode_image(image_data)
cv2.imshow('frame', x)
cv2.waitKey(1)

message = input("Enter 'q' to quit: ")
cl_socket.sendall(message.encode('utf-8'))

cl_socket.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

TCP is a streaming protocol.  Bytes go into the socket and come out of the socket in the same order, but not with the same "message" breaks.

Do not assume `.send()` sends all the data.  Check the return value and transmit the remainder if it wasn't all sent, or use `.sendall()`.

Do not assume `.recv(n)` receives `n` bytes.  Check the return value.  It can return any number of bytes from 1-n or zero if no more data *and* the socket was closed.

You need to buffer receives and extract complete "messages".  You decide what constitutes a complete message.  In your case you have sent a 4-byte message length header followed by data of that length, so you must ensure that you actually receive 4 bytes, then "length" bytes by buffering and calling `.recv()` until the message is complete.  You could also receive part of the *next* "message" so be sure to maintain a buffer and keep any extra for the next message.

One way to manage a buffer is to use `socket.makefile()` to wrap a socket in a file-like object.  Then methods like `.read(n)` (return exactly n bytes unless socket error or socket close, like reading a file) and `.readline()` (read up to and including a newline character) are available.  Make sure to `.flush()` a writable makefile object to ensure data is flushed to the socket.